# Downloading files from an HTTP that looks like a FTP

Tags: python, http, ftp, download

Thinking that I was dealing with a ftp site, I tried to login to e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/ using this Python simple script:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftolib.FTP("e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov")
ftp.login()
```

I got this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

which is probably because the site is actually HTTP.

Now, my goal is to download files from the folders within the site, and it seems like ftplib is not working in this case, or am I wrong? What solution would you suggest?

Comment: And why do you think it's FTP? Because the index page looks roughly like how a browser renders an FTP site?  Easy enough to check; it's all HTML over HTTP. (Hint: View source.)

Comment: @tripleee : Yes, at first it looked like ftp. Another hint for you: copy and paste the url inside a text editor.

Comment: Hmm? Copy+paste yields `http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/` for me.

Comment: @tripleee : So you can see the "http://" part which means the site is HTTP, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this simple solution:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD11A1.005/2012.07.11/BROWSE.MOD11A1.A2012193.h00v08.005.2012196013549.1.jpg","Downloaded.jpg")
```